# Unit testing with Zend_Session_Namespace

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, session, phpunit

I'm writing unit tests for a login system - but having difficulties with interacting with the Zend_Session_Namespace object. I'm using the Zend_Test extensions to the PHPUnit framework (ZF 1.10, PHPUnit 3.4.5)

Test

```
public function testAuthFailure()
{
  $request = $this->getRequest();
  $request->setMethod("POST");
  $request->setPost("username", "testUser");
  $request->setPost("password", "testPassword");

  $this->dispatch("/auth/login");

  $this->assertModule("auth");
  $this->assertController("login");
  $this->assertAction("validate");

  $loginSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace("login");
  $this->assertFalse(is_null($loginSession));
  $this->assertObjectHasAttribute("messages", $loginSession);
  $this->assertFalse(empty($loginSession->messages));
  $this->arrayHasKey("error", $loginSession->messages["error"]);
  $this->assertEquals($loginSession->messages["error"], "Could not log you in with that username and/or password");
}
```

Current controller/action code

```
public function validateAction()
{
  $loginSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace("login");

  if (!$this->buildForm()->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
    $loginSession->messages["error"][] = "Please enter your username and password";
  }

  $loginSession->messages["error"][] = "Could not contact the authentication server";

  $this->getResponse()
    ->setHttpResponseCode(303)
    ->setHeader("Location", "/auth/login");
}
```

My unit test is failing at `$this->assertObjectHasAttribute("messages", $loginSession);` - whereas I would expect it to fail on the actual content of the message.

I have these lines in my phpunit bootstrap:

```
Zend_Session::$_unitTestEnabled = true;
Zend_Session::start();
```

How do I confirm that the session message is correctly set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a total facepalm moment when re-looking at this problem today:

The "message" property on my Zend_Session_Namespace is actually a magic property (accessed using __get and __set), and is not identifiable through reflection (which is how PHPUnit tests for the existence of the property under the call to assertObjectHasAttribute).

Removing the assertion from the test allows it to continue, and my test now fails at the expected point and not prematurely.